# eventlet.greenthread.sleep VS time.sleep in monkey-patched environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching, eventlet, green-threads

We're running a server on eventlet green-threads + monkey-patching everything.
I need to implement wait loop with periodic check, and I want to put sleep inside.

Is there any difference between :

```
eventlet.greenthread.sleep(1) AND time.sleep(1)
```

in monkey-patched environment? I'm wondering if monkey-patch handles time.sleep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the same in a monkey-patched environment. `eventlet` monkey patches `time.sleep` by default:

No monkey patch:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep.__module__
'time'
```

With monkey-patch:

```
>>> import eventlet
>>> eventlet.monkey_patch()
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep.__module__
'eventlet.greenthread'
```

The only way it wouldn't be monkey-patch is if the `eventlet.monkey_patch` call specifies a subset of modules to monkey-patch, leaving out `'time'`:

```
>>> import eventlet
>>> eventlet.monkey_patch(socket=True, thread=True)
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep.__module__
'time'
```